# Javascript - Convert string to date and compare dates

Tags: javascript, date

I have date from the date picker which I am accessing as -

```
var transdate = $j("input[name='enterdate']").val();
```

resulting in `transdate = "6/22/2015"`

I need to test if the entered date is between two dates which are defined as 
`startdate = '2015-02-01'` and `enddate = '2015-07-30'`

How do I convert the transdate in yyyy-mm-dd format in the following code -

```
if ((new Date('transdate')>= startdate ) && (new Date('transdate') <= enddate )) {

alert("correct date entered");
}
```

Comment: I'm confused as to why your date picker is using M/DD/YYYY. The HTML5 date input uses the standard YYYY-MM-DD, are you sure you can't configure yours to do the same?

Comment: @JesseKernaghan—lots of browsers in use don't support input type date. Likely the OP is using a library and plugin.

Comment: @RobG I am aware, I was simply wondering if that was a configurable option for the one they were using. A plugin that uses the YYYY-MM-DD format (and a lot of them do) would let OP use a simple string comparison.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Similar questions have been asked many, many times but I can't seem to find a duplicate. Given the unreliability of the Date constructor to parse strings, the simplest solution is to parse the string yourself:

```
function parseMDY(s) {
  var b = s.split(/\D/);
  return new Date(b[2], b[0]-1, b[1]);
}
```

Answer (score 7):

The string is not in the only format [defined to be handled by the `Date` object](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.1.15). That means **you** have to parse it (with regular expressions or `String#split` or whatever), or use a library like MomentJS that will parse it for you. Once you've parsed the dates, you can compare them with `<` or `>`, etc.

Do not rely on `Date` to parse strings it's not defined to parse. You will run into implementations or locales where it doesn't work.

`"6/22/2015"` is trivial to parse with a regular expression:

```
var rex = /^(\d+)\/(\d+)\/(\d+)$/;
var match = rex.exec(transdate);
var dt = match ? new Date(+match[3], +match[1] - 1, +match[2]) : null;
```

That uses the `Date` constructor that accepts the parts of the date as individual numeric arguments (year, month, day). The `+` converts strings to numbers. The `[x]` are capture groups from the regex. You have to subtract one from the month because months start with `0` in JavaScript.

Answer (score 7):

[Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) is a small handy library for dates that makes this easy.

```
moment('6/22/2015', 'M/D/YYYY')
  .isBetween('2015-02-01', '2015-07-30'); // => true
```

Note that only the first (US format) date string needed an explicit format string supplied.

Moment can be useful for the parsing alone, eg. even if not using `isBetween`:

```
var transdate = moment('6/22/2015', 'M/D/YYYY').toDate();
var startdate = moment('2015-02-01').toDate();
var enddate = moment('2015-07-30').toDate();

transdate >= startdate && transdate <= enddate // => true
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is the [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/alaksandarjesus/z546w1mL/) of you output.

Moment.js will give you good flexibility in coding.

**Dont forget to add jquery and moment.js in your html**

```
var transdate="6/22/2014";
var convertStringToValidDate = new Date(transdate);
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#selectedDate").text(transdate);
$("#validDate").text(convertStringToValidDate);
converttoformat = moment(convertStringToValidDate).format("YYYY-MM-DD");    
$("#converttoyyyymmdd").text(converttoformat);   

    if(moment(converttoformat).isBetween('2015-02-01', '2015-07-30')){
        $("#result").text("Date lies in between");
    }
    else{
        $("#result").text("Date is out of scope");
    }


});
```